# Работа с AJAX___________

Tags: jquery, ajax

Мне нужно сделать так, чтоб когда я нажимал одну из этих кнопок вся страница не перезагружалась, а только данные. Ну или здесь отпишитесь. Просто у меня не получается и я даже не знаю как сделать.

p.s Спасибо что выслушали
p.s Все это должно работать на AJAX JQUERY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз не знаете с чего начать, я Вам предложу начать с [документации](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

За тебя никто писать не будет. я тебе набросал пример, чтобы быстрее мог понять, но делать за тебя я не буду. пример **очень** приближен к твоей задаче.

Код главной страницы, куда необходимо погружать содержимое другой страницы

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Main page</title>
<style type="text/css">
  ul li {
    list-style: none;
    }
  div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    }
</style>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#main_nav a').click(function(){
                    $('#result').load('another_page.html');
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="main_nav">
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>`

Код "дочерней" страницы `another_page.html`, которая будет подгружаться в блок с `id #result`.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Another page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Привет!я содержимое другой страницы!!!</p>
</body>
</html>`

UPD: Молодой человек, учитесь самостоятельности. Вы должны переработать материал и, если что-то не получается, тогда задавать вопрос, чтобы Вам что-то подсказали. А подход *"сделайте за меня"* совсем не верен. И, кстати, спасибо за голоса!

Comment: Может вы мне поможете?

Comment: Давайте в скайпе обсудим мне все это пишут, но это нифига не понятно.

Comment: Ну а что там может быть непонятного? По клику на пункте меню загружать в определённый блок через `.load()`, допустим, другую страницу. Всё предельно просто.

Comment: во ты мне можешь все вот это объяснить LeD4eG напиши мне все это в скайп

Comment: если вопрос решён, его нужно закрыть.